# can I swap out Pool pump switch

Tags: electrical, switch, pool, smart-switch, filter

Need advice. My current pool timer doesn’t work and I turn on my pump manually daily.  I’m going out of the county on vacation in a couple of weeks and I want know if it’s possible to replace my current on/off 30amp 120-277v double pole switch with a wifi or programmable switch like this one I found on amazon.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No.

[image]

If you look at the specifications listed on the [Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VM9WXCH), you'll see that it's only rated for 15 amps (for a resistive load, which a motor isn't) or a 1/2 hp motor. Based on the current 30 amp switch, there's no way this would survive switching your pump motor.

To use this, you'd need to add a 30 amp relay/contractor and figure out how to fit it safely.

You're much better off replacing the broken pool timer with the same.

Comment: Google says a 1/2 hp is only about 370 watts.

Comment: @Huesmann Yes - this indicates this timer cannot handle anywhere near its full load with an inductive load. 370 watts vs 1,800 watts of resistive load. This makes the timer even less suitable for the large motor in the pool pump.

Answer (score 0):

The switch is labelled as being double pole. Most smart or timer switches are single pole. You could have the timer activate a double-pole relay, I suppose, but that isn't a sole part for part replacement.